# How to convert (int* int) list to (int: list) in F#

Tags: list, f#, seq

I have a sequence pairwise like:  Original = [(0,0); (1,2); (3,4)]
I would like to convert this seq of (int *int) to a seq of int Final= [0,0,1,2,3,4]
Can anyone please suggest me the way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `List.collect`

```
[(0,0); (1,2); (3,4)] |> List.collect (fun (x,y) -> [x; y])
```

In your question you say you want a List at the beginning but at the end you say Sequence, anyway for sequences collect is also available.

For more information `collect` is the monadic function [bind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)#Collections) or the operator `>>=` in some languages (SelectMany in C#) which for lists/sequences is equivalent to a map followed by a concat.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is to use sequence expressions - I quite like this option, but it is a matter of personal preferences:

```
[ for a, b in original do
    yield a
    yield b ]
```

Comment: the original list is a list of tuple of 2 items. Should I have a bracket around and b, in other words

    [ for (a, b) in original do
    yield a
    yield b ] ?  (I've tested the code, both ways gave the same results) Which one is correct and why ?>

Comment: If they both work and they both produce the same results, then they're both correct. Parens are only mandatory in F# when the lack of them leads to ambiguity and compiler errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
[(0,0); (1,2); (3,4)] |> List.map(fun (x,y)->[x; y]) |> List.concat
```

ie. map tuple sequence to a list of lists, and then join the lists together

or

```
[(0,0); (1,2); (3,4)] |> Seq.map(fun (x,y)->seq { yield x; yield y}) |> Seq.concat |> Seq.toList
```

I came up with the longer Seq version first, because the Seq module traditionally had more operators to work with.  However, come F# 4, Seq, List, and Array types will have full operator coverage.